# Creating equivalent output with jaxb

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling

I'm doing a project for a customer where i have to read XML files, analyse them, do some corrections when needed and write them out again.
I used JAXB to solve this, just unmarshalling the file, working with the resulting objects and marshalling the objects back to files when finished.

Sadly my customer has the requirement that the XML files should not be changed, except the parts intentionally changed by my program.
This causes trouble because JAXB changes XML files when marshalling, for example by changing the order of attributes or by moving the definition of a namespace up to the root element of the XML structure.

Do i have any possibilities to change the output of the JAXB marshaller to match the expectations of my customer? Or if this is not achievable with JAXB, are there any alternative XML libraries for Java which can preserve the XML files as much as possible?
I am currently trying to use DOM and SAX for this, but it seems like a big hassle to get them to work like i want to...

Comment: Attribute order shouldn't matter and as such controlling it is not supported, see https://community.oracle.com/thread/977397.

Comment: The problem is less the tool, but more XML itself. There are many different representations allowed (for empty nodes, whitespaces, etc...) for the same document. Cheapest way for the customer is to give him training.

Answer (score 0):

JAXB's `Binder` mechanism may match your requirements.  Where `Marshaller` produces a new XML document, `Binder` will apply the changes back to the `DOM` that was used as input.

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import org.w3c.dom.*;

public class BinderDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        File xml = new File("input.xml");
        Document document = db.parse(xml);

        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);

        Binder<Node> binder = jc.createBinder();
        Customer customer = (Customer) binder.unmarshal(document);
        customer.getAddress().setStreet("2 NEW STREET");
        PhoneNumber workPhone = new PhoneNumber();
        workPhone.setType("work");
        workPhone.setValue("555-WORK");
        customer.getPhoneNumbers().add(workPhone);
        binder.updateXML(customer);

        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer t = tf.newTransformer();
        t.transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(System.out));
    }

}
```

**For More Information**

I have written more about JAXB's `Binder` on my blog:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/jaxb-xml-infoset-preservation.html

Comment: Wow, that is a really cool feature of JAXB. Only Problem is that having the data in a DOM is not enough for my requirements. DOM still changes some things, like the order of attributes. Or am I missing a feature of DOM here that allows me to keep the order fixed?